# How to memory profile GCP Cloud functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, memory-leaks, google-cloud-functions, profiler

I have a Node.js code which runs GCP cloud function. Functions runs fine with 1-2 instances, but when its instance level is higher, there is some kinda memory leak & memory graph on GCP CF shows **99 percentile**, How can I do a effective memory profiling?

My R&D lead me to Stackdriver Profiler, but it says **CF is not supported** yet [here](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/about-profiler).

Comment: I am not aware of a CF tool to help you. When I have these types of problems, I run my code at my desktop. It is fairly easy to build the startup code to call a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no specific tool GCP offers to test Cloud Functions for a memory leak. As John mentioned, an option would be to test the code you're using in your function **locally**.

You might find this [**article**](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/memory-leaks-in-nodejs-quick-overview-988c23b24dba) about memory leaks in Node.js useful as a reference.